# Div cannot be added to another div after remove

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

I am new in jquery and web programming and making a dynamic html controls.

If user choose a value from combobox, I create a html control which has choosed by user. After

that I remove previous html control.

this is my main div thatI want to copy to another div

```
<div id="MainContents" style="display: none" >
        <form action="../../newCV/AsyncUpload" id="photoform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              <p> <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" /></p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Save my profile" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and this is part of my jqeurty function

```
case "Date":
                $('#c3').remove();
                $("<input name=\"c3\" id=\"c3\" type=\"date\"/>").appendTo("#changeablecontrol");

                break;

            case "Picture":

                $('#c3').remove();

                var html = "<div id=\"c3\" name=\"c3\"></div>";
                $(html).appendTo("#changeablecontrol");

                $('#MainContents').css('display', "inline").appendTo('#c3');
```

first time, If I choose picture, maintcontents div append to div c3. It okay. But If I choose Date (that remove c3) and again choose Picture, that time It doesnt append. Because When I choose Date, it also removes MainContents div in my form. I dont know why it removes MainContents div. Because its in different part. Then when I choose picture second time in combobox, Its not in my form.

I tried to create maincontents with html code in jquery but that time, some functions dont work.

this is my changeablecontrols div

```
  <div class="creatediv2" id="changeablecontrol">
    @Html.TextBox("c3","" ,new { onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('create').click()" })
</div >
```

I used append instead of appendTo

```
html += "<div id=\"MainContents\">"
                html += "<form id=\"photoform\"  action=\"../../NewCV/AsyncUpload\"   enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" method=\"post\">"; //method=\"post\"
                html += "<input type=\"file\" id=\"photo\" name=\"photo\" />";
                html += "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"uploadbtn\" value=\"Upload Photo\" /></form>";
                html += "</div>"
                $('#c3').append(html);
```

but this jquery function doesnt work

```
   $(function() {

            $("#photo").makeAsyncUploader({
                upload_url: "../newCV/AsyncUpload",
                flash_url: '../Scripts/swfupload.swf',
                button_image_url: '../../Content/blankButton.png',
                disableDuringUpload: 'INPUT[type="submit"]'
            });

        });
```

I hope that I explained my issue..

Comment: Cannot see #changeablecontrol html code! BTW, you should set a jsfiddle

Comment: @roasted, I added it. for jsfiddle, I cannot add it, i think. Becaue my somecode is written in razor

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/   to let other developpers see what is exactly your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont know why it removes MainContents div. Because its in different part.

No it's not. You have append it to #c3, so when You delete (remove) the #c3 You also remove all his childrens. Maybe You should use append(), instead of appendTo() function?

Comment: Nice catch, effectively, #MainContents is append to c3, so removing c3 will remove #MainContents too.

Comment: as I wrote you, If i add html control, my upload function doesnt work.

Comment: OK so just to clear everything. You want to add two difrent controllers in case of clicking for some buttons. Why dont You put those in difrent divs and then hide, and show that one that should be displayed (i.e. using toggle() ). And then before send remove from html the div that You don't need. Sorry for my english

Comment: @bumerang, I edited my question, could you look it, thank you

Comment: @bumerang, I actually have 4 controls which depends on user choose. I remove c3 div and create again and add another control. but this part occurs problem

Comment: But do You need use only on control at a time? This sounds strange put them in difrent divs and display if needed. And for the code You put above:  upload_url: "../newCV/AsyncUpload", You shouldn't put relative path. it should be like: upload_url: "full_path/newCV/AsyncUpload",  - without domain part

Comment: Your welcome. I'll look later to check if You have finish it.

Comment: @bumerang, thank you again, I added the answer. this way looks better :) I didnt want to do this, but I see that is clear :)

Answer (score 0):

As  [bumerang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1939671/bumerang) said, I created divs for each controls and changed their display values from hide to inherit.

```
  <div class="creatediv2" id="changeablecontrol">

      <div id="filecontent" style="display: none" >
        <form action="/NewCV/AsyncUpload" id="photoform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              <p> <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" /></p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Save my profile" /></p>
        </form>


  </div>     

<div id="textcontent" style="display: inherit">
    <input id="c3-1" name="c3" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('create').click()" type="text" value="" />

</div>

<div id="longtextcontent" style="display: none">
      <textarea name="c3" id="c3-2" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
</div>

<div id="datecontent" style="display: none">
       <input name="c3" id="c3-3" type="date"/>
</div>


    </div >
```

my jsquery functions

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#photo").makeAsyncUploader({
                upload_url: "/newCV/AsyncUpload",
                flash_url: '/Scripts/swfupload.swf',
                button_image_url: '/Content/blankButton.png',
                disableDuringUpload: 'INPUT[type="submit"]'
            });

        });
    </script>
```

and this one is changing displays' value

```
  var val = cmb.options[cmb.selectedIndex].text;

        switch (val) {
            case "Text":
                $('#textcontent').css('display', 'inherit');
                $('#longtextcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#datecontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#filecontent').css('display', 'none');

                break;
               case "Long Text":

                $('#textcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#longtextcontent').css('display', 'inherit');
                $('#datecontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#filecontent').css('display', 'none');

                break;

            case "Date":

                $('#textcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#longtextcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#datecontent').css('display', 'inherit');
                $('#filecontent').css('display', 'none');

                break;

            case "Picture":

                $('#textcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#longtextcontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#datecontent').css('display', 'none');
                $('#filecontent').css('display', 'inherit');
                break;

        default:

            break;
        }
```

thank you :)